# trouble with jquery and session var

Tags: php, jquery, session, session-variables

I need to change some session var while clicking on image.

So I added a class on the concerned pictures (that pictures are flags). It is for translating a website.

In my website, language is defined using session var, and by default it is set to english.

So poeple can change them

Here is a kind of image `<img src="images/fr.png" title="French" alt="French" class="flag" id="fr">`I get. So I added class and Id,

then I've written the following code using jquery to make it on the same page with no reload :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("img.flag").click(function(){
                    // Get the src of the image
                    var src = $(this).attr("id");

                    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
                    $.post("lib_php/session.php", {"lang": src});
                })
            })
        </script>
```

On the page where I send the post I have simply that code :

```
<?php
session_start();
    // do any authentication first, then add POST variable to session
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];
?>
```

The trouble is that nothing is changing, all remains the same.

I do not know where I'm wrong

Anylind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that `lib_php/session.php` is reachable? try it using the absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `session_start();` in file that you are using `<script>`

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("img.flag").click(function(){
                    // Get the src of the image
                    var src = $(this).attr("id");

                    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
                    $.post("lib_php/session.php", {"lang": src});
                })
            })
        </script>
```

#### Alternative Function

I tried with `$.ajax` and it works. Please try this one

```
<img src="images/fr.png" title="French" alt="French" class="flag" id="fr" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('img.flag').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: {lang: src},
        url:'lib_php/session.php'
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note:** Important that `<script type="text/javascript">` is after the `img` tag

Comment: yes I have session start on the main file wher I have the script

Comment: I tried your codes and works with only after adding `session_start();`

Comment: yeah I've seen that but I really do not understand why the translation does not appear

Comment: thanks it works fine, I've done an alert but In fact you know I have this code `if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr') { include_once('lang/fr.php'); } elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'en') { include_once('lang/eng.php'); } elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'de') { include_once('lang/de.php'); } elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru') { include_once('lang/ru.php'); } elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ch') { include_once('lang/ch.php'); } else { include_once('lang/fr.php'); }` what I don't understand is that variable of session has changed but the page included did not change

Comment: Do you want all strings change with new language without page reload?

Comment: yeah it is the goal I'm looking for because when I realod the page the variable of session is lost

Comment: I guess, you can't do this if you are "including" the page using php. Php is server side. By the time it has got to the client browser it has been parsed and sent as HTML. I think, this issue is another question for stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say by just looking at the code above. As far as I'm aware the syntax looks fine for both the jQuery and the PHP. I'd imagine your issue would be caused by one of the following:

- You're not POSTing the information to the correct page. Way to check: in your PHP `echo $_POST['lang']`
- You're not including `session_start()` across all of your PHP pages.
- You're not even doing the post due to not including jQuery properly - check your browsers console to see if a POST call is actually being fired.

Comment: As i've seen the var does change but My translation does not appear, I'm a bit lost, In fact I have the following code on the header `if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr') {
    include_once('lang/fr.php');
} elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'en') {
    include_once('lang/eng.php');
} elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'de') {
    include_once('lang/de.php');
} elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru') {
    include_once('lang/ru.php');
} elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ch') {
    include_once('lang/ch.php');
} else {
    include_once('lang/fr.php');
}` As my variable of session have changed why does it not appear ?

Comment: 1) Use a [Switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of your if-elses and 2) I've got no idea, echo the "lang" value out just above. Also make sure that that statement comes AFTER you set it.

Comment: Also, why do you have two conditions which both return `lang/fr.php` - if you want it to be your default then in your original if-else conditions it should just be in the `else` (in a switch, `default`)

Answer (score 1):

try the following to check if everything is ok :

```
$.post("lib_php/session.php", {"lang": src} ,function(data)
{
    alert (data);
});
```

then in session php :

```
echo  $_SESSION['lang'];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply the alert show the good variable but It does not seems to change my translation please he a look http://apple-wholesale.eu/ when you click on the flag of language